# Can I check what values were returned in a ComboBox.DataBound event handler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have a Kendo ComboBox which binds to a remote service.  I want to check the values fetched from the server during data bound, how can I do that?

```
function ComboBox_DataBound(e) {
    e.sender.value() // <--- this is not set yet
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the _values returned during data bound_? The values fetched from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the callback you can use

```
this.dataSource.data()
```